# 項目間に余白が残り続けてしまいます...。

Tags: css, sass

#### 前提・実現したいこと

Flexを採用しdivをメニューのように整列させていますがうまく並びません

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

```
エラーメッセージは特段発生されておりません
```

#### 該当のソースコード

```
<div class="fluid-wrap">
  <div class="el"></div>
  <div class="el"></div>
</div>


body {
  margin: 0;display: flex;justify-content: center;
}

.fluid-wrap {
  width: 80%;
  background: brown;
  height: 100vh;  display: flex;

  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

div>div {
    flex: 100%;
}

.el {
  height: 20px;
  background: #ffa;
}
```

#### 試したこと

align-itemsが関係しているかと思っい、alignをstartに修正しましたが特別な変化が見れませんでした

#### 補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）

sass:4.11.0
windows:10

Comment: マルチポスト - https://teratail.com/questions/194624

Answer (score 1):

今回の場合、flex アイテムの配置ではなく、**flex アイテム間の余白の扱いが問題**です。つまり、`align-items` プロパティではなく、`align-content` プロパティの値を考えなければなりません。

[CSS Flexible Box Layout Module Level 1](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/) によれば、`align-content` プロパティの初期値は **stretch** です。この値では、交叉軸での各アイテムの合計が flex コンテナの寸法になるように、余白が均等に挿入されます。

> #### § 8.4. Packing Flex Lines: the align-content property<sup>[[1]](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#align-content-property)</sup>
>
> - Name:   align-content
> - Value:  flex-start | flex-end | center | space-between | space-around | stretch
> - **Initial:  stretch**
> - Applies to: multi-line flex containers
> - Inherited:  no
> - Percentages:    n/a
> - Computed value: specified keyword
> - Canonical order:    per grammar
> - Animation type: discrete

そのため、質問者さんの実現したいことを行なうには、以下のように CSS を修正する必要があります。

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.fluid-wrap {
  width: 80%;
  background: brown;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;  /* 追加 */
}

div>div {
  flex: 100%;
}

.el {
  height: 20px;
  background: #ffa;
}
```

```html
<div class="fluid-wrap">
  <div class="el"></div>
  <div class="el"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: 若干の差異はあるものの、内容がほぼ一緒なのは単なる偶然でしょうか？ - https://teratail.com/questions/194624#reply-288658